# Showing that pressure reaches its max on the boundary of ideal fluid in a stationary flow

Tags: complex-analysis, applications, fluid-dynamics

The question is to **show that the pressure in the stationary flow of ideal fluid achieves is maximum value on the boundary (and not at an interior point, unless the pressure is constant)**.

I've come up with:

If the pressure is constant, then, for whatever value $p$ is, that value is, of course, the maximum. So, assume $p\neq$ constant. From Bernouilli's law, we know that
$$
\rho\frac{u^2}{2}+p=\text{ constant}
$$
Denote the constant to be $C$. Then, we know that the velocity of the flow achieves it's minimum value along the boundary. That is,
$$
u_\text{min}=u_\text{boundary}
$$
So, for the velocity $u_0$ of any flow not along the boundary, we have
$$
u_0>u_\text{min}=u_\text{boundary}
$$
Now,
$$
\rho\frac{u^2}{2}+p=C \Rightarrow u=\sqrt{\frac{2(C-p)}{\rho}}
$$
So, we have
$$
u_0>u_\text{min}\\
\sqrt{\frac{2(C-p_0)}{\rho}}>\sqrt{\frac{2(C-p_{u_\text{min}})}{\rho}}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{2(C-p_0)}{\rho}>\frac{2(C-p_{u_\text{min}})}{\rho}\\
\Rightarrow C-p_0>C-p_{u_\text{min}}\\
\Rightarrow p_{u_{\text{min}}}=p_\text{boundary}>p_0
$$
Hence, we have that the pressure along the boundary is strictly greater than the pressure along any other point in the flow when velocity is at its minimum. That is, $p_\text{boundary}=\boxed{p_\text{max}>p_0,}$  where $p_0$ is any point on the interior.

This solution doesn't sit well with me, though. I don't like that I'm making the assumption that $u$ is a min on the boundary. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you know what equation $p$ satisfies? The statement is a strong maximum prnciple for $p$.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. I believe $p$ is suppose to be satisfying the Bernoulli equation.

Comment: Bernoulli's equation only applies to stream lines - you assume it applies everywhere. On top of that, your reasoning is circular - you assume that u is minimized on the boundary, which of course implies that p is maximized if you assume Bernoulli's equation holds. EDIT:
I forgot that if you assume that the flow has vanishing curl, there's a theorem (by Crocco, I believe) that states that Bernoulli's equation can hold constant throughout an entire flow. If that is indeed your case, then try and relate the magnitude of the velocity to an analytic function and apply the Maximum Modulus Principle.

Comment: @user116061 I've converted your post to a comment. It's definitely useful, but answers should answer the question at least in significant part.